# colorize files on MacBook terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, macbook

I have a dedicated remote Linux server, and was able to add this code to my ~/.bashrc file:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
LS_COLORS='di=34:fi=0:ln=36:pi=5:so=5:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=35:*.rpm=90'
export LS_COLORS
```

which colorized directories, symlinks, etc. etc.

However, using Terminal on my MacBook, I do not see a .bashrc file present in my ~ directory.

What is the equivalent way of doing this for a MacBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LS_COLORS='di=34:fi=0:ln=36:pi=5:so=5:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=35:*.rpm=90'
```

into you `~/.bash_profile` (`~/.bashrc` works as well but is for non interactive shells). Create the file if it does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  For those reading this, I did need to exit the connection and log in again to see it.

Comment: Also for those reading, I needed to create .bash_profile - it didn't exist yet.  Out of curiosity where is the "brain" among my shell files which says "Look for a file called .bash_profile if it exists" ?